# Problems with Arabic text and line height in EditText

Tags: android, android-custom-view, text-rendering

I'm overlaying colored text over parts of a user-entered string in an `EditText`. However there isn't consistency in the line heights of Arabic text. `getLineHeight()` works fine for Latin text, but it is too small for Arabic text. I had to use `getLineBounds()` to get the correct height of Arabic lines of text. Unfortunately `getLineBounds()` is too large for Latin text.

However, this error only occurs on my phone (Google Pixel 1 on Android P). When I test in on an emulator (Nexus 9 on Android 8.1), [`getLineBounds()` also returns a value that is too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6E7x.png). I don't know what is causing this discrepancy.

[image: <code>getLineBounds()</code> also returns a value that is too large]

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.getClipBounds(rect);

    int baseline = getBaseline();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (!lines[i].isEmpty()) {
            highlightLastWord(canvas, i, baseline);
            if (i == currline) {
                if (!usingArabicText) {
                    canvas.drawText(suggestions.toString(), 4 + rect.left + sidebarWidth + textPaint.measureText(lines[i]), baseline, suggestPaint);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawText(suggestions.toString(), rect.right - sidebarWidth - textPaint.measureText(lines[i] + suggestions.toString()), baseline, suggestPaint);
                }
            }
            if (textPaint.measureText(lines[i]) > rect.width() - getTotalPaddingLeft() - getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                if (usingArabicText) {
                    getLineBounds(i, lineBounds);
                    baseline += lineBounds.height();
                } else {
                    baseline += getLineHeight();
                }
            }
            if (usingArabicText) {
                getLineBounds(i, lineBounds);
                baseline += lineBounds.height();
            } else {
                baseline += getLineHeight();
            }
        } else {
            baseline += getLineHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some images or code?

Answer (score 3):

It's because Android P uses "Fallback line spacing" when displaying non-Latin text.

To fix that add this to your constructor of the custom `EditText`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
    setFallbackLineSpacing(false);
}
```

If you're worried about this making your text too compact you can use this in your constructor too.

```
if (usingArabicText) {
    setLineSpacing(15, 1);
}
```